# Hide the title of module by default in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am working on module of joomla 2.5.
I have created the module  but i need to hide the title of module by default , The nature of joomla backend is  that it sets the show title to 'show' by default . I need to change to 'hide' by default. The best possible solution i have come up with changing the field 'showtitle' to '0' from module table in db.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->update('#__modules AS a');
$query->set('a.showtitle = 0');
$query->where('a.module = "mod_name"');
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

I am not sure , whether this is the best way , If any joomla pro has better way to achieve the task , Please suggest .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with changing your template code, 
in your template you find a code which include module in to template

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="xhtml" />
```

change this code to

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i am working on it,  will give the feedback

Comment: shall i put that command in default.php in my module ? Sry i am new in joomla . can you elaborate little.

Comment: no need to change default.php file in module, you need to change template index.php file. on this file found for the moduel code 

<jdoc:include type="modules" name="YOUR-POSITION" style="xhtml" />
change this to 
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="YOUR-POSITION" style="none" />

Comment: i dont want to edit core files. what my module does is that it loads few javascripts as soon as admin publish the module. I want to hide the title of module by default as admin install the module.